# Variance of squared sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

$X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are *i.i.d* random variables with zero mean and unit variance. Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, I want to express $\mathrm{Var}[X^2]$ in terms of $n$, $\mathrm{E}[X_1^4]$, and constants.

I'm able to make the following progress:

$$\mathrm{Var}[X^2] = \mathrm{E}[X^4] - \mathrm{E}[X^2]^2$$
$$ = \mathrm{E}[X^4] - (\mathrm{Var}[X] + \mathrm{E}[X]^2)^2$$
$$ = \mathrm{E}[X^4] - (n\mathrm{Var}[X_1] + 0)^2$$
$$ = \mathrm{E}[X^4] - n^2$$

But then I'm lost on how to approach the $\mathrm{E}[X^4]$ term. I know it can be expanded into $\sum_i \sum_j \sum_k \sum_l \mathrm{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l]$, but I don't know how it can be further simplified.

Comment: What makes you think that this can be further simplified ? The numbers $E[X^k]$ for different $k$ are independent of each other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's a problem in our textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the fourth moment of the sum $X$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^4]
&= \sum_{i,j,k,l} \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l].
\end{align*}

What complicates the computation is the overlapping of indices. But one crucial observation is that, if one index is different from all the others then the term vanishes. For instance, if $i \notin \{j, k, l\}$ then $X_i$ is independent of $X_j X_k X_l$ and thus

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l]
= \mathbb{E}[X_i] \mathbb{E}[X_j X_k X_l] = 0. $$

So removing all such terms from the summation, any surviving term must satisfy that for each index $i$ there is another index which has the same value as $i$. This leaves only two possible cases:

- **Case 1.** We can have $i = j = k = l$. In this case, we have $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^4]$.
- **Case 2.** We can pair indices such that indices in different pairs have different values. So we have $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]^2$.

So it follows that

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^4] = n \mathbb{E}[X_1^4] + 3n(n-1)\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]^2. $$

You can simply further by plugging $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] = 1$, which follows from the assumption.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how you got the $3n(n - 1)$?

Comment: @ZizhengTai, It is of combinatoric origin, and is the way of grouping $\{i,j,k,l\}$ into two pairs and assigning different values to them from $\{1,\cdots, n\}$. This can be done as follows: (1) Assign any value $a \in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ to $i$, (2) Pick any of $j,k,l$ to form a pair with $i$. (3) Form the other pair by grouping the remaining two indices, and assign the value $b \in \{1,\cdots,n\}\setminus\{a\}$ to this pair. This gives total $n\times3\times(n-1) = 3n(n-1)$ ways.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have reached the solution, as the final result must be in terms of $n$ and $E[X_1^4]=E[X^4]$.

Comment: Can you explain on the $\mathrm{E}[X_1^4] = \mathrm{E}[X^4]$ part?

Comment: Which equality ?

Comment: Please see my edited comment.

Comment: The justification is the same as the one you used for the variance.